# Excel Array Overwrites, Need Append

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

All, I have been Googling and attempting, and then more Googling and attempting. I am attempting to search multiple sheets for negative values, copy the entire row(the value not the formula), and then add them all to a central location for viewing. ANY pointers would be greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
Sub Button6_Click()

Set Sh1 = Sheets("Destination Sheet")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each v in Array ("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
  On Error Resume Next
  Worksheets(v).Range("M10:M").AutoFilter 1, "<0"
  Worksheets(v).AutoFilter.Range.EntireRow.Copy
  Sh1.Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: `Sh1.Cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`

Comment: @VBasic2008 - Yes I did! thanks.  Long day.   Michael - Add `.Offset(1,)` after `.End()` or you'll overwrite the last-occupied row.

Comment: `Range("M10:M")` looks off

Comment: Tim, that worked perfectly thank you very much. How do I give you credit? A side note, when the code executes it filters every single sheet to show only the negative values. Is it possible to leave the sheets alone, yet still copy the negative rows. I assume its something akin to taking out the ."AutoFilters"?

Comment: Posted as an answer, so feel free to accept that to mark your question as answered.  You could avoid the autofilter and copy row-by-row using a loop, but autofilter is faster/easier and if you want the sheet back to its previous state then you can just remove the filter after the copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the typical way to append a row to an existing table:

```vb
Sh1.Cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Note this requires each row in the destination sheet to have value in ColA: otherwise the paste may occur in the "wrong" row.